# Caliburn Micro run code on label click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm using `WPF` alongside `Caliburn.Micro`. I want any code to be run when a label is clicked. I tried some googling and found out about `cal:Message.Attach`.

XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="Info" Content="Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="305,440,0,0"
VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" cal:Message.Attach="[Action ShowAboutWindow()]"/>
```

C#:

```
public void ShowAboutWindow()
{
    MessageBox.Show("xyz"); // just to test whether ShowAboutWindow is executed whatsoever (see explanation below) 
    WindowManager.ShowWindow(new AboutViewModel(EventAggregator, WindowManager, SettingsManager));
}
```

However, `ShowAboutWindow` isn't run whatsoever. I added a `MessageBox` to make sure that it isn't the `WindowManager` screwing it up.

How can I achieve what I desire?

EDIT 1: What I had tried even before was adding a `public void Info()` method to the `ViewModel`, as this works for buttons. But it didn't in this case.

Comment: can you show us your BootStrapper, secondly are you using a DI/IoC container?

Comment: Also why use a label? A styled button could look just as plain as a label and you will have your click event available by default.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm using a button now, however, it's disabled no matter what I try. Even if I set the property `IsEnabled` to `true`, it's disabled...?!

Comment: @Çan do you have a guard property or method like `CanShowAboutWindow`. These guard are used by the framework to enable/disable controls.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Çan  way too much to get into here. update your post to reflect the changes you have made. check documentation here http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/ for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try attaching to the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event to simulate a click event after the mouse left button is released.

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp] = [Action ShowAboutWindow()]"
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this attempt. However, still -nothing- happens. Just nothing.

Comment: Only option since Label doesn't have a click event handler.

Comment: @Çan where is the method `ShowAboutWindow` on the view model or code behind of the view?

Comment: Is it in a context menu or similar (that might break the DataContext/ViewModel link)?

Comment: Sorry for the rather late reply but it was solely my fault. I forgot to enable the whole grid and you couldn't really determine this from viewing it. It works. Checked as correct answer!